# Suggested methods for generalizing survey results from one population to another, with individual level data for both

Tags: sample-weighting, transportation

I have two datasets. The first dataset includes my variables of interest, as well as a large set of respondent characteristics. My second dataset includes matching respondent characteristics for a set of respondents randomly drawn from my target population.

I would like to estimate descriptive statistics around my variables of interest for my target population.

I am familiar with generalizability and transportation methods used when you have an RCT dataset as well as an individual-level target population dataset, solving a similar problem. However, those methods focus on estimating treatment effects in the target population, rather than a descriptive statistic.

can also see how I could construct summary statistics about my target population and reweight my first dataset, but this seems to neglect all the value in having individual-level responses in my second dataset.

Could you suggest what methods I should be looking into to address this question?

Comment: This sounds almost like the problem of polling, which has a standard solution. Can you clarify how reweighting neglects the value of individual-level responses?